# Python Lists: How can I search for another element or duplicate item in a list

Tags: python

I have a list say `p = [1,2,3,4,2]`
Is there any way of returning bool value `True` if it contains a duplicate using only find, indexing, slicing, len() etc methods and not dict, tuple etc.

I used this code:

```
for e in p: 
   duplicate = p.find(e, e+1) 
   if duplicate in p: 
       return True
```

Comment: Why the requirement to not use `dict` et al (I assume this includes `set`)?

Comment: Can you please format your question?  http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @ Mr E, I don't know how to format it here

Comment: @yesboy - I have formated it for you this time. Click "edit" and have a look how it was done.

Comment: @yesboy: There's formatting instructions right next to the Ask a Question box.

Comment: @NPE Because I haven't learned that yet.

Comment: @yesboy: This might be just the opportunity! :)

Comment: What does the `etc` mean in `find, indexing, slicing, len() etc methods and not dict, tuple etc.`? Is this a homework restriction?

Comment: @MrE It's much more reasonable, with a new user, to just format the question yourself. You can complete the task faster than those instructions can be read and applied. The new user will see the improvement, and want to imitate it in the future.

Comment: @Eric I do, frequently

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the easy way:

```
return len(p) != len(set(p))
```

A less efficient way that doesn't use `set`:

```
for i in range(len(p)):
   if p[i] in p[i+1:]:
      return True
return False
```

This second approach is not very idiomatic, but avoids all but the most basic features of the language (including tuples).

Here is one more way:

```
while p:
   e = p.pop()
   if e in p:
      return True
return False
```

This is simple, but does modify the list.

One final way I am going to demonstrate is:

```
s = sorted(p)
for i in range(1, len(s)):
   if s[i] == s[i - 1]:
      return True
return False
```

This works by sorting `p` and then comparing every pair of consecutive elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I was searching.

Comment: I wonder if it's within requirements to use `sorted` and compare each item to the previous item.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: I don't know, but I've included it all the same. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

You could also use [`list.count`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

```
def has_duplicates(p):
    for e in p:
        if p.count(e) > 1:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> p = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2]
>>> len(set(p)) == len(p)
False
```

You can find [more information about sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) in the [Python Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you have to do it this way, you could do:

```
def has_duplicates(lst):
    for i, e in enumerate(lst[::-1]):
        if lst.index(e) != len(lst) - i - 1:
            return True
    return False
```

This iterates through the list in reverse order (since `index` searches from the start of the list). But it's better simply to do:

```
def has_duplicates(lst):
    return len(set(lst)) != len(lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using collections.Counter

```
>>> import collections
>>> p
[1, 2, 3, 4, 2]
>>> if collections.Counter(p).most_common()[0][1] > 1: 
...     print('duplicate found')
... 
duplicate found
>>> if collections.Counter(set(p)).most_common()[0][1] > 1: 
...     print('duplicate found')
... 
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple way to do it.  It may be slow for very large lists.

```
def has_duplicates(lst):
    for e in lst:
        lst = lst[1:]
        if e in lst: return True
    return False
```